# where to config iopub_data_rate_limit on Colaboratory?

Tags: io, google-colaboratory

I have the following error when loading model weights in Colaboratory:

> IOPub data rate exceeded. The notebook server will temporarily stop
>   sending output to the client in order to avoid crashing it. To change
>   this limit, set the config variable
>   `--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.
>
> Current values: NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0
>   (bytes/sec) NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
>
> UnicodeDecodeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         6 if if_init_from_ckpt_file:
>         7     print('load saved model from', ckpt_file)
>   ----> 8     model.load_weights(ckpt_file)
>         9

Answer (score 4):

An IOPub error usually occurs when you try to print a large amount of data to the console. Check your print statements - if you're trying to print a file/data variable that exceeds 10MB, its likely that this caused the error. Try to print smaller portions of the file/data.